# Updating data from subpartition when the subpartition name is unknown

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, update, oracle-11g

Thanks to [JSapkota](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68931/jsapkota) who helped me pull the subpartition name as per below query

```
select subobject_name from user_objects where data_object_id IN 
(select dbms_rowid.rowid_object(rowid) from TABLE 
WHERE DOCID = 'S00102981655537O')
```

Which gives me a result

```
SUBOBJECT_NAME               
--------------
MAR16_IN_UK
```

Now if I update that ID using below statement it works

```
UPDATE TABLE SUBPARTITION (MAR16_IN_UK) 
SET FLAG = 'Y'
WHERE DOCID = 'S00102981655537O';
```

**1 rows updated**

But the same query by dynamically pulling the subpartition name would throw an error

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SUBPARTITION (select subobject_name from user_objects where 
data_object_id IN 
(select dbms_rowid.rowid_object(rowid) from TABLE 
WHERE DOCID = 'S00102981655537O')) 
SET FLAG = 'Y'
WHERE DOCID = 'S00102981655537O';
```

**Error**

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Version: Oracle 11g

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Just simple update statement would do that. Or if you want to update partition independently then can use partition key.

Comment: The reason I am doing that is because I am checking the Explain Plan by both providing the partition name and not providing it. I see that the Bytes are high if I dont provide the partition name.

Answer (score 2):

you can not do in dynamically like this. partition name has to be known and the time when statement is compiled.

But you can use `PARTITION FOR` clause:

```
UPDATE TABLE T PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE('31-JAN-2007','dd-MON-yyyy')
...
```